# uint is 32 bits no matter the system is 32 or 64 bits?

Tags: c#

in C#, uint is a UInt32 type so it will be always 32 bits long no matter the OS is 32 or 64 bits. Am I right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that's right. `uint` is always an alias for `global::System.UInt32` (and yes, that's always 32 bits :). The same logic applies for the other predefined aliases.

The only built-in value type I can think of which has a size varying by platform is [`IntPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr), for obvious reasons. (Any value type which *composes* an `IntPtr` would have the same behaviour, of course. `SafeHandle` springs to mind.)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you're. `UInt32` always represents a 32-bit unsigned integer.